# Application.Current.Shutdown() is not killing my application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I've just started a new C#/WPF application and am using the NotifyIcon from the [WPF Contrib project](http://wpfcontrib.codeplex.com). I can start the program, add an "Exit" MenuItem to the NotifyIcon's ContextMenu, and link that item to a method that simply runs Application.Current.Shutdown().

This closes the main window and the NotifyIcon, but something continues to run - running from VS, it does not leave debug mode. What is still running? Or how can I check?

**EDIT**

I've just tried adding a button that calls Application.Current.Shutdown(), and that exits properly. It's only when called from the NotifyIcon that I have a problem. Why would this be?

To clarify, I have the following XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="VirtualBoxManager.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:av="http://schemas.codeplex.com/wpfcontrib/xaml/presentation"
    Title="VirtualBox Manager" Height="350" Width="525"
    ShowInTaskbar="False" WindowStyle="None">
<Grid>
    <av:NotifyIcon Icon="/icon/path"
                   Text="Virtual Machine Manager"
                   Name="notifyIcon">
        <FrameworkElement.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Exit" Click="MenuItemExit_Click" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </FrameworkElement.ContextMenu>
    </av:NotifyIcon>
    <Button Content="Button" Click="button1_Click" />
</Grid>
```

Both button1_Click and MenuItemExit_Click are identical, but the former successfully exits the app and the latter does not.

Further experimentation: even if I move Application.Current.Shutdown() into another method and call that instead, adding a layer of indirection, still the button works and the icon doesn't.

**Solution found?**

Just found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867380/), who's solution does work here. I don't totally understand what's happening, so if anybody cares to explain I'd appreciate it.

Comment: If there is a clean way to "comment out" that NotifyIcon portion of your app, you might give that a shot to see if that is what is keeping your process from exiting.

Answer (score 30):

You coult try `Environment.Exit(0);` It kills the process with the given exit code. Exit code 0 states the application terminated successfully. It might be more 'rude' or 'not-done' but perhaps this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This does force the app to shut, but the whole thing freezes for a second before doing so.

Answer (score 11):

I found if I create threads that are not set to "background", the main window/etc will close, but the threads will keep runnings.

In other words, only background threads close themselves when the main thread ends. Regular threads, aka Thread.IsBackground = false, will keep the process running.

Try using thread.IsBackground = true;

P.S. I made the assumption that you used threads somewhere.

Comment: You may be using third-party libraries which are "invisibly" using foreground threads...

Comment: I've faced with the same situation. Thank you :)

Comment: awesome. saved me

Answer (score 11):

I think the author's answer is the best one here, but hasn't really been called out. `Application.Shutdown()` seems to require to be executed on the dispatcher thread to work. Try this if you run into the problem:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(Application.Current.Shutdown);
```

Answer (score 6):

I have had the same problem in my application. In my start up module (Startup.cs) I found that this works for me:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

The code is as follows:

```
class StartUp
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {

    try
    {
        Process[] processes = new Process[6];
        App app = new App();
        app.InitializeComponent();
        app.Run();
        Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill(); //Must add this line after app.Run!!!
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
    }
```

This goes directly to the process causing the hang. There is no need to iterate through multiple processes.

Comment: Really? Yopu think the solution to the problem is just to have the application kill it's own process... BAD IDEA!

Comment: Because you have no idea as to the application's state when the process gets killed by the user pressiong the close button. For example what if your app is in the process of writing to a file?

Comment: It is a good idea to have a crash-safe design anyway. Counter-intuitive but so much more robust...

Comment: Arguably it's better to do this as a backup solution.

Call Application.Current.Shutdown(); and then after a set time period if the process is still running kill it with Process.Kill().  

If you want to be extra sure that long running processes complete on exit, you could add use of Process.WaitForExit with a predefined max time limit.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to do that! just simply override `OnClosing` method inside the main window like this:

```
        protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // If you try to dispose it from ViewModel, you might get a CrossThreadException.
                notifyIcon.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate
                {
                    notifyIcon.Dispose();
                }));
            }
            catch { }
            base.OnClosing(e);
        }
```

and then in everywhere of your main application code, no matter you are in View or ViewModel or everywhere, just call it like this:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();
```

I had the same problem but I fix it like that.

Update: **You should not use `Environment.Exit(0);` method. it throws the same exception.**

Comment: `Application.Current.MainWindow.Close()` has the added advantage that it doesn't ignore the `CancelEventArgs.Cancel` property like `Application.Current.Shutdown()` does.

Answer (score 2):

**Make absolutely sure you aren't creating any Window objects that you never Show()**

For some insane reason WPF adds windows to `Application.Windows` on CREATION and not when you first call `Show()`. If you have `Application.Current.Shutdown` set to `ShutdownMode.OnLastWindowClose` then these windows (that you never even displayed) will prevent the app from shutting down.

Lets say you open a child window of your main window like this

```
Console.WriteLine("Window count : " + Application.Windows.Count);
var window = new OrderDetailsWindow();
Console.WriteLine("Window count : " + Application.Windows.Count);
window.Show();
```

Before you even call `Show()` you'll see that Applications.Windows now shows 2. The app will only shutdown when Windows.Count is zero.

---

*My situation:*

I have a WindowFactory that takes a viewmodel and creates a window for the model passed in.

Somehow over the years my copy and pasting had yielded this :

```
 if (viewModel is DogModel)
 {
     window = new DogWindow();
 }
 else if (viewModel is CatViewModel) 
 {
      window = new CatWindow();
 }
 if (viewModel is DogModel)          
 {
     window = new DogWindow();    
 }

 window.DataContext = viewModel;
 window.Show();
```

So when `viewModel` was `DogModel` I ended up creating TWO `DogWindow` objects so `Application.Windows.Count` was 3 when I expected it to be 2. Since `Application.Shutdown` was waiting for all windows to be closed it never got activated - even though I never even opened the window!

I would always have assumed that `Show()` was needed to activate the window, but that was a wrong assumption - so my app never exited.

Answer (score 0):

It may be living in the processes. Here's a sample of how I check / kill the process

```
       const string str = "MRS_Admin";
        foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (process.ProcessName.StartsWith(str))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(@"Killing process " + str);
                process.Kill();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me.
I wanted to kill the application from within a class
`Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Send);`