# Process exit on closing WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

A WPF appplication is hosted using

```
System.Diagonistics.Process
```

I have subscribed to the exit event of the process. I wanted to know how the window's close triggers the exit event.

Comment: If it is the main window I assume that triggers a process exit automagically. Are you seeing something else?

Comment: Yes it is a main window. But wanted to know the relationship between window close and process. How does process will come to know that window is closed and process has to exist? how this communication happens. Basically wanted to know the internals

Comment: not the internals but the property that defines when it closes: `Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;`

Comment: Well, that is a pretty broad question. Start reading here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071137/application-current-shutdown-is-not-killing-my-application

Comment: thank you rene1. Will go through the shared link

Comment: For internal working see the reference source: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Application.cs,a4358325bb26999d,references

Answer (score 1):

The process exits when the call to `Application.Run()` in the `Main` method returns.

`Application.Run()` in turns calls `Dispatcher.Run()` which keeps the dispatcher loop running until the framework calls `App.CriticalShutdown`, assuming the `App.ShutdownMode` is set to either `ShutdownMode.OnLastWindowClose` or `ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose`. Otherwise you shut down explicitly.

If you look in the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Window.cs,e438dc91640a8d15), you'll see an example of how `App.CriticalShutdown` is called from the `Window` class:

```
if (((App.Windows.Count == 0) && (App.ShutdownMode == ShutdownMode.OnLastWindowClose))
    || ((App.MainWindow == this) && (App.ShutdownMode == ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose)))
{
    App.CriticalShutdown(0);
}
```