# Close the main application from a different thread

Tags: c#, html, wpf, multithreading, browser

I am developing an application which is written by c# + HTML + Java Script in the following structure: 
the base window is a WPF MainWindow class that opens a thread which creates a web page. This thread handles all the UI events.

The WebBrowser XAML code is:

```
    <WebBrowser x:Name="CordovaBrowser" 
        Opacity="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
        Loaded="CordovaBrowser_Loaded" 
        Unloaded="CordovaBrowser_Unloaded"   
        LoadCompleted="CordovaBrowser_LoadCompleted" 
     />
```

The problem is that I want to close the application from the HTML thread.
I cannot use App.Current.ShutDown() because I'm not in the main UI thread (I've tried to do so but got an exception).

(BTW: For who knows PhoneGap: my application structure is very similar to how the Win8 PhoneGap is built.)

Can anyone please help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `Environment.Exit(0);`?

Comment: process.Kill() would definitely do it, not sure if it's ideal

Comment: I tried your first suggestion and it worked. I just want to know if it's a common way to do that. Is'nt there a better way to communicate between threads?

Comment: In user space, you cannot communicate with threads that are running on another core. Environment.Exit(0) requests the OS to terminate the process and, since the OS kernel can stop threads in any state on any core, should always work.  It is, of course, a pretty hard stop which may, or may not, be desired.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is (edited and taken from [Application.Current.Shutdown() doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867380/application-current-shutdown-doesnt))

```
ThreadStart ts = delegate()
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    });
 };
 Thread t = new Thread(ts);
 t.Start();
```

See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/de-DE/68bea444-1fa7-4948-8b8c-bf61fbc6dc2b/how-to-exit-a-wpf-application

Comment: that what i've tried, but as i wrote i got the exception: "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it"

Comment: The thread issue is addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867380/application-current-shutdown-doesnt , use the dispatcher